# How to apply a glass shader on my imported geometry?

Tags: uv, objects, shaders, import

I'm new to Blender so I'm doing all my modelling in *Maya* and transfer to Blender using wavefront obj. I have create a simple wine glas, no texture applied, just geometry. I can apply color to it but when I increase the transmission value nothing happens.

Do I need to import my .mtl file? Tried to unwrap the UV's as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the Eevee renderer.

Go to Properties Editor > Render Properties tab and check **Screen Space Reflections** as well as **Refraction**. It brings a glass look to your material.

With Glass object selected go to Shader Editor > Properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> switch to *Options* tab and check **Screen Space Refraction**.
This enables other objects visible behind glass.

[image]